# Usage case of locking nontrivial object in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

In C#, before invoke lock(), one often first create a dedicated object, which serves solely for the purpose of being locked. Let's call such a usage case as locking a trivial object.

But the language nevertheless allows locking nontrivial objects, although it is often deemed bad practice and suggested to be avoided.

The language is designed in such a way that you can write code such as

```
lock(this);
lock(typeof(MyType);
lock("something");
```

and then carry the above mentioned tip everywhere for the sake of best practices. Why doesn't prohibit such usage by introducing a lockable class/interface in the first place (in that case, you can only apply lock() to lockable objects)?

The only reasonable explanation I can think of is that, in some cases (rare but important), locking a nontrivial object actually makes difficult things easier. If so, could somebody give an example?

Comment: You have a `WebClient` that, due to historical reasons, has been injected into fifteen separate objects (all of the same class / type). Which is a problem since the objects run in parallel and `WebClient` is not thread-safe. The proper fix is to stop them all sharing the `WebClient`. The quick fix (which is important since you need to ship right now) is to lock on the single `WebClient` object (in that class) when you interact with it. There is one example.

Comment: The other, likely simpler, explanation is that your approach of having lockable objects would be more work. And doesn't help solve many real-world problems. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/